# Java: export to an .jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, executable, extract, exe

I'm trying to export a program in Eclipse to a jar file.

In my project I have added some pictures and PDF:s. When I'm exporting to jar file, it seems that only the `main` has been compiled and exported.

My will is to export everything to a jar file if it's possible, because then I want to convert it to an extraditable file, like .exe-file.

But how?

Comment: please refer this link https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm

Answer (score 62, accepted):

No need for external plugins. In the **Export JAR** dialog, make sure you select *all* the necessary resources you want to export. By default, there should be no problem exporting other resource files as well (pictures, configuration files, etc...), see screenshot below.
[image: JAR Export Dialog]

Comment: Correct, assuming the necessary resources don't include other jar files.

Comment: In my project/program, Im using a database that is created when I shut down the program. So I cant pack the database file. When I follow you direction and try to start the jar-file I get the message: Failed to load Main-Class manifest attrebute from ..._path_...

Comment: @Pedro - yes, the JAR can be executable, in the next view in the wizard you can choose the main class.

Comment: Could I save list of selected resources permanently with project?

Answer (score 10):

Go to file->export->JAR file, there you may select "Export generated class files and sources" and make sure that your project is selected, and all folder under there are also! Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

[FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) can help you in this case.

In addition to the"Export as Jar" function which is included to Eclipse the Plug-In bundles all dependent JARs together into one executable jar.
The Plug-In adds the Entry "Build Fat Jar" to the Context-Menu of Java-projects

This is useful if your final exported jar includes other external jars.

If you have Ganymede, the Export Jar dialog is enough to export your resources from your project.

After Ganymede, you have:

[image: Export Jar]

Answer (score 2):

One more option is [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/). There is an [Eclipse Plugin for WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/eclipseplugin.html) that allows you to export your application as a single executable with necessary jars/classes embedded.

(full disclosure: I work on this project)