# How to implement a tiered "selection tree" in Swing? (Or: is there an existing implementation?)

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I need a Swing component that will let me display a tree-structured list of items, and allow the user to select or de-select an arbitrary subset of those items, with the ability to select or deselect an entire subtree's worth of components by picking that subtree's parent.  (Basically, something similar to the Eclipse "Export JAR file's" dialog (an image of the relevant dialog is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse) - I basically want the "Select resources to export" component, but for a Swing application.)

[image]

I know I can do this by creating a custom TreeCellRenderer, a custom TreeCellEditor, and a custom TreeModel - but that seems like an awful lot of work.  Are there any good off-the-shelf implementations that I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also take a look at [JIDE components](http://www.jidesoft.com/) to see if they have something like that.

Comment: JIDE Common Layer contains a CheckBoxTree and is open source.

Comment: Bingo - CheckBoxTree is *exactly* what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are talking about a JTree.  It is typically used to display hierarchical data such as a file structure but it can be modified to do other things.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html

Comment: Looks like exhaustion got the best of me and I didn't even see that you had tagged jTree already.  As far as I know this is the best way to do it.  Sorry for telling you something you already know.

Comment: :) That's not tradition, Google gives you results on 1.4 every time ( because they are more linked I guess ) Replacing `s/1.4.2/6` use to give you 404 but I guess Sun ( sigh , oracle ) notice the trend and now redirects you to the correct one.  :... Just... if any one was wondering :P

Comment: @Support - multilanguage SO: My fault for being too elliptical, Oscar. I meant the traditional approach using `JTree`.

Comment: Oh I see :P  I actually didn't really knew why was I writing that comment, until I was about to finish it .. so... I just click on send :P

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider NetBeans' [`Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html). Because it descends from `JTable`, you can specify multiple selections that include subtrees and leaf nodes.

```
outline.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
    ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

Addendum: Looking at your picture, you might be able to make use of  [`CheckRenderDataProvider`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/CheckRenderDataProvider.html).