# Unable to load main-class for jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have developed an application using Eclipse IDE. After creating the application I exported the project in jar format. When I am trying to run this jar file, I get the error: Unable to load main class. Please Help.

Comment: Please post the command you use to 'run' the application (like: `java -jar myjar.jar`) as there are 'millions' of reasons why running a jar could fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are exporting your project as a jar (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse)), you must specify your main class in the export Jar wizard.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should work always:

```
java -cp MyJar.jar pkg.name.MyClass
```

I'd prefer this anyway because it causes less classpath trouble compared to the `java -jar` way of starting a java application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a runnable jar file. From Eclipse 3.4 you can do that by choosing Export, Java, Runnable Jar File. If you also want to include dependencies have a look at the [Fat Jar plug-in](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/).