# Is there a way to add a 'libs' folder to my project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The only way I know for adding additional libraries in a  Java project (in Eclipse) is by manually adding them to the project's build path.

Is there a way in which I just create a folder, and anything inside it (.jars, to be more precise) is added to the classpath? Can I do something like that in eclipse?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410803/a-simple-question-about-lib-folder-in-eclipse) with *Add library*

Comment: Better Start using a dependency manager Ivy or Maven.

Comment: @Aniket Thankur, not a useful comment, especially when adding code not in a repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Classpath Variable ( Preferences)which points to your directory  and add it to build path.

Use this in your project ( build path - Add Variable)

For Ex: If you want to have C:\MyDev\Libs in your build path

Eclipse-Windows-Preferences-Java-BuildPath-Classpath Variables- New
Create a new entry calls MyDevLibs pointing to C:\MyDev\Libs

In your project-build path- configure build path - Libraries (tab) - Add Variable

This should do.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i will suggest is started using maven it handles the dependency problem very well

or

create a lib folder Put all the JARs into a lib folder inside of your project.

Now you can select all JARs in that folder, right click -> Build Path -> Add To Build Path.

Or just you can define a "User Library" which contains all the JARs and add that single item to your project's build path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to care about the classpath but also about the build.properties. If it is not part of the build properties, the libraries will not be part of the generated *.jar file.

Let assume that your plugin is named *'rts.core.libs'* and the project includes a folder named *'native/dll'*.

Your file **.classpath** will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="rts.core.libs/native/dll"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

and your **build.properties** file looks like

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               native/
```