# How to convert source and class files into 1 executable for an applet?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet

I have finished a project - jave applet - for a friend.  To run the project I am simply clicking Run Application within eclipse.  How do I convert my project into 1 file, such that my friend can simply open that one file and the applet will start?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to distribute Java-based software?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838403/how-to-distribute-java-based-software)

Comment: Just create a jar file with all your class files and resources. With Eclipse this is done by using the Exporting wizard which you can get via the File - Export menus. Then follow the instructions.

Comment: The simplest way is to create `.jar` file and specify class with `main` function in manifest.

Comment: @Banthar: not a duplicate since this deals with Eclipse. Tags to be added to question.

Comment: /Your user would be better served by getting a link to a [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) launch application, rather than a web page with an applet embedded.  Note also that applets will work when not in a Jar.

Comment: @Banthar *"specify class with main function in manifest"*  An applet has no 'main' class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just export your project as a jar, either directly through eclipse or by using something like Ant.

Then your friend just puts the following code in their html...

```
<applet code="yourMainClass.class" archive="yourArchive.jar" codebase="yourCodebase/">
```

Comment: oops, I forget to mention about the HTML side of things. 1+ and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate, you create a Jar file which is done in Eclipse using the Export wizard. Press the `File` menu then the `Export` sub-menu, then follow the instructions:

- Select Jar them Next
- Select the needed files and resources, create a Jar file name,  then press Next
- Select options, then Next
- Select a main class -- I know this is important for a desktop application, but I'm not sure if it's needed for applets.

Comment: When I click browse on the main class, there are then no options.  And if I try to leave this field blank, the jar file does not open.  I get the error: Failed to load main-class manifest...  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use eclipse export option.
Go to File->Export->Java (from list) -> Runnable JAR File (if you dont have it use JAR File instead)->Choose the project you want -> Choose Destination folder -> Finish.

In the folder you have choosen, will be a .jar file.