# putting picture in java program using MyEclipse GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, executable, exe

I want to add a picture to my GUI program created using Eclipse and MyEclipse (for GUI visual design) from the resource pictures I pasted earlier in the project.

I managed to load pictures that lies just beside the .JAR file using

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("imageFile.jpg"));
```

But I want to use the image from my resources "src" folder directly , so that the .JAR file is a standalone file yet loads pictures nicely.

I tried to make it

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/ldtlogo3.jpg"));
```

I use this method when exporting the .JAR file
[Java: export to an .jar file in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

Use the overloaded `ImageIO.read` method taking an `InputStream` as a parameter, and use `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream()` to get this input stream. `getResourceAsStream` loads a resource from the classpath (and thus from the JAR of your application). Its api doc will tell you which path it expects.

Note that the src directory is used to hold your Java source files. The jar doesn't contain it. It contains the .class files, in a hierarchy which directly maps the package hierarchy. Eclipse will automatically "compile" the image file by copying to the output directory, along with the .class files.

Comment: I did this and it shows a null exception: 

InputStream a=LoadImage.class.getResourceAsStream("src/imageFile.jpg");        
  
image = ImageIO.read(a);

Comment: @sherif get rid of the `src/`.

Comment: @sherif: open your jar file with a zip tool (winzip or anything else), and use the path of the image file. For example: /com/yourcompany/yourproject/imageFile.jpg. If the image is at the root of the tree, use /imageFile.jpg. The src attribute exists only in your development tree. At runtime, the jar is used, which does not contain the src directory.

Comment: @JB Nizet
Thank you man, it worked :)
but I did something else, I moved the pictures inside the package that has the main function, then referred to the resource with just it's name, I assume your method will work too , thank you