# How to make a jar with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an Eclipse Java project? How can I make a jar for the project?

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse

Comment: -1 for not searching on stackoverflow or google. Asked so many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File - Export, and from here you can export a standard jar file or an executable Jar File .

At the the end of the wizard is also possible to save the export as ant build file, that is useful because let you customize the export through the build.xml.

Answer (score 1):

These can help you.

[Create jar using Eclipse](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#firstjava_export)

[Create JAR file in Java & Eclipse](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse.html)