# how do I add classpath to the exported runnable java .jar file using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, classpath

so my projects have a lot of classpath variables set in the run configuration -> classpath tab in eclipse...

but once I exported the project as a runnable java jar file, none of these classpaths are exported to the jar's manifest file despite having specified this run configuration during the export dialogue....

how do I get eclipse to add these classpath variables to the exported jar's manifest?

besides doing everything manually of course...

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.htmlor http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0587.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own manifest file and ask eclipse to use it in the "Export->Jar" wizard.

You can also try "Export -> Runnable Jar" in the latest versions of eclipse. I have not tried it, this generally is *supposed* to include the referenced libraries, so it might include the classpath variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't seem to have an option for creating a manifest, I think the export option is for library files rather than runnable jars. If I remember correctly you have to manually sign+add a manifest to a jar at once? Not sure though. But you would have to manually sign it anyway so not a massive deal.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post - i believe it answers your question.

[Java: export to an .jar file in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse)