# Eclipse , Java Jar Export ,not loading resources

Tags: java, eclipse

I am building a java desktop application in Eclipse .
And i need to either export it as a JAR and run through command prompt or export as an Executable JAR.

The project structure is

```
 -- src
 -- resources
 -- bin
 -- build
 -- Icon
 -- build
```

And after exporting it , when i try to run the jar file , the icons are not getting loaded in the interface .

Please help me out in this regard .

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the images in a resource folder instead of a normal folder, they will export.

Make a new resource folder by rightclicking your project, new, Resource Folder. Add the path you want (like 'src/java/resources') and put the images in there.

(at least, this did it for me.)