# How to build jar using Eclipse "Export as jar option" with a properties file

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public xFbConfigReader()
{

    //props = new Properties();
    propsdatabase = new Properties();

    try 
    {
        // load a properties file
        InputStream dbin = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/properties/database.properties");


        propsdatabase.load(dbin);

    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I keep My properties File named 'Database.properties' in a folder where the project is named 'Properties'.

When I do a Export as jar in Eclipse . The Properties Folder is visible.

[image: You can see the properties folder]

But When I run the program it shows that there is a NUll point exception in dbin.

So which means I require the proper way to form a jar in Eclipse .Kindly suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse

Comment: Try removing the leading "/" from "/properties/database.properties". Check the path from where the program is being executed.

Comment: try neatbean IDE its a great tools for java developer

Comment: @TJ it does not work that way too

Comment: @Mayank .. sure I ll try using Netbeans sometime. but I need a solution with the current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution while handling properties file would be reading

```
static Properties databaseproperties= new Properties();
    static {
        try {
            connectionProps.load(YourClassName.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("databaseproperties.properties"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception is " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This is better approch because

- we can move our properties file to someother folder.
- And infact  we can keep properties folder out side of jar.    say you can create
  a folder called Configuration where you can include all the
  properties files. As it is out side of jar you can change the
  properties file when ever is required.
- For change in properties
  file no need to unjar it.

(OR) simply you can make this change no need to think about directory structure

1. Step 1: Move properties file to SRC
2. step 2: change this line as
   follows

   InputStream dbin = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/database.properties");

This is not much different from previous code as it is anyway stays inside the JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting null pointer exception because properties file is not loaded try to use 
FileInputStream to load  the properties as follows
FileInputStream dbin = new FileInputStream("/properties/database.properties");
properties.load(dbin);

Comment: Yes Gouse I understand that. But If u observe in the Image attached  showing the extracted tree structure of jar file. the file does not get loaded though  you can see that properties folder is present.