# Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after import JAR

Tags: java, android, jar, runtime-error

I got a problem...

I made a Jar (called "GeoFence.jar"), that I have to use on a Android Project.
So, what I done is:

1. Look In so many webs HowTo's
2. create "libs" folder in the android project.
3. add my JAR (manually)
4. then I went to Java Build Path and checked that my JAR was included to the Android Dependences.
5. finally I made the necessary Imports to use the class I need from JAR.

After do all of this, I runned my App, and it throws this error:

[image]

and I don't understand what's going on, cause, I Fixed the Project Properties and cleaned it. And it's still not working.

Here is how i have the structure and the build path.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "java.lang.ClassDefFoundError" ? Seriously ? Can we see the error ?

Comment: @Anthon, thanks for Editing ^^ now is better to see my problem ^^

Comment: It's `NoClassDefFoundError` not `ClassDefFoundError`.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to you Android Dependencies folder, you should be able to expand the GeoFence.jar file. This way, you should be able to find the class `com.elias.polygon.City` if you keep expanding subfolders.

If you **CANNOT** see it, you probably made an error in exporting the jar file.

- To solve the export [see this question on so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse)

If you **CAN** see the class, you have an error in your build path/ project properties

- To solve the project setup, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

Comment: I can see the class City inside the Android Dependencies Folder if i Expand subfolders.

The second link It was what I did to add my jar.

But it's still not working :(

Answer (score 3):

for adding jar use below two stpe: but for you just do 2nd.

```
1. Your Project -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jar -> yourjar.jar
2. Your Project -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export --> Select All --> OK
```

After taht just clean your Project and RUN.

Comment: That's how I did, but eclipse is giving the same problem

(also y cleaned and fixed properties)

Comment: Yes, here is the log file:
04-04 14:45:42.211: E/AndroidRuntime(26187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-04 14:45:42.211: E/AndroidRuntime(26187): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.elias.polygon.City

04-04 14:45:42.211: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):  at com.elias.testinsidecity.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:49)

Comment: I can say that my Jar uses another lib called JavaAPIforKml, and it's included in the jar file, because I can see it inside de Android dependencies folder with City.class

I don't know if it can cause some problem

Comment: i think so.. try to clean your project & try again.

Comment: Doesn't work yet doing all u said to me.

But... in Android, can we use the 
java.awt.geom.Path2D;
java.awt.geom.Point2D;

Because can be this imports used in City.class that are giving me the problems???

Answer (score 1):

the problem that I had, was that the jar I wanted to import, used some packages that in android are not "allowed" so I had to do in a different way.

After that, it happens the same, but the problem was that the Jar was Build in v1.7.
When I builded in v1.6 android accepted it.

So, first of all look for:

1. Don't use packacges that in android are not allowed
2. Look in which version is builded the solution.