# NoClassDefFoundError in android intellij project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror

I have added an external library as a module in my Intellij Android project. During compilation there is no error. But when I try to run the app I get the **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15810874/1168654

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar But this is on intellij IDE

Comment: Is the scope of your library set to 'Compile', and not 'Provided'?

Comment: @Nebelmann Yes it is set to 'Compile'

Comment: Please share a sample project to reproduce it.