# Export Java GUI map from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I wrote a Java App - a calculator to convert temperature between Kelvin, Celsius and Fahrenheit.

The app finally works with a bunch of clearly bugs but anyway, my question is how to export my Java App out of Eclipse. So I can single click and open that app without IDE.

Thanks. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean an export to a runnable jar file?

File => Export => Java => Runnable Jar file. Then select yout project and main class and done.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a jar file from your project.
Here's a great [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse) that shows you how to do it, it also has pictures :-)