# Exporting jar file

Tags: java, jar

I guess this's a very newbie stupid question, but im not getting sth related to exporting.

To export my java project (lets call car project) into a car.jar file, after selecting some options, i have to select the export destination of the car.jar file im creating. At first, i thought that was the directory in which the car.jar would be placed after eclipse had created it. But when I select the directory it says that "Export destination must be a JAR file, not a directory." But how can i have any .jar file in my pc assuming car.jar is the first jar file im creating??? 
I just dont get the fact that i need an archive of the same type of the archive im trying to create....

I already tried to create a zip archive and then choose this zip file as my export destination, but it's not working....

Heelp??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: export to an .jar file in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse)

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: Just give it a name ending in .jar when you export it.

Answer (score 1):

right click on the your eclipse project on the project explorer panel

choose export

type in the export destination "jar". It will filter the options to "jar file" and "runnable jar file" (maybe other according to the eclipse plugins you have installed)

select "jar file"

in the jar file specification window, there's "select export destination". click on browse and select some directory and, in the box in the bottom, type "x.jar" (or the name you want)

click on save

it will fill the box with the jar file name and it will enable the "finish" button

click on "finish"