# Export as Executable Jar File in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, executable-jar

I just want to export a simple application in to a runnable jar or Mac OS X .app format. It is exporting fine but both don't run. The app runs without any errors in Eclipse.

[image]

The applications loads data from Userdata.dat file.
MainScreen is the Main Class.

Comment: Have you tried to run it via command-line prompt?

Comment: What do you mean by *When I try either it is exporting fine but both don't run*? You need to be a bit more descriptive as to what issue is happening for us the help you

Comment: Kindly give the error you are getting.

Comment: I believe your questions has already been asked.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse
Cheers :)

Comment: @E.Doroskevic No command line prompt

Comment: @MikeElofson I've had something similar and you do not get an error message. The problem is in the JRE and the way it is installed on the OS. I am sure if he would run it in CMD it would execute. Another way around it would be making a batch file and executing it instead.

Comment: @MikeElofson It is exporting the project as a runnable jar file but when I open the jar file nothing happens. Same thing happens for Mac OS X bundle

Comment: @E.Doroskevic How do I do that

Comment: @user3506498 f you want a batch file to run a jar file, make a blank file called runjava.bat (or any other name the essence lays in *.bat) with the contents: java -jar "C:\myjarfile.jar"

Comment: @E.Doroskevic Running on Mac

Comment: @E.Doroskevic I ran it with Terminal It gave the following error Could not find or load main class .Users.Sri.Desktop.Messenger.jar

Comment: @user3506498 you can execute batch files on Macs you have to elevate permission. Else I recommend you to look into deleting your current JRE and install it all again.

Comment: to run any other class having "public static void main" in some package : ava -cp "full-path-of-your-jar" Main @user3506498

Comment: I changed my class name to Main and it worked @E.Doroskevic Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest route is probably upgrading or re-installing the Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

Or this:

- Open the Windows Explorer, from the Tools select 'Folder Options...'
- Click the File Types tab, scroll down and select JAR File type.
- Press the Advanced button.
- In the Edit File Type dialog box, select open in Actions box and click Edit...
- Press the Browse button and navigate to the location the Java interpreter javaw.exe.
- In the Application used to perform action field, needs to display something similar to C:\Program Files\Java\j2re1.4.2_04\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" % (Note: the part starting with 'javaw' must be exactly like that; the other part of the path name can vary depending on which version of Java you're using) then press the OK buttons until all the dialogs are closed.
  Which was taken from [here](http://windowstipoftheday.blogspot.com/2005/10/setting-jar-file-association.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a basic `.command` file with the runnable jar in the same directory as the command file.
Just open up TextEdit and type this code:
`java -jar JarFileName.jar`
Save it as `run.command` and place the jar file in the same directory as `run.command`
(Directory meaning folder)
If you're on Windows, do the exact same thing, except instead of a `command` file, save it as a `.bat` file.