# Editing a .java file and recompiling

Tags: java, ant, compilation, compiler-errors

Newbie java question, I am sure this has been answered but cannot find a solution anywhere :(

I want to use this java program contained here http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-tibco/files/

wich consists of a ant-tibco.jar file

and many .java files contained here .\ant-tibco\src\org\apache\tools\ant\taskdefs\optional\tibco

I want to edit a line in one of these .java files, but after that I am not sure how to compile to commit these changes, I have tried javac but keep getting "cannot find symbol" exceptions.

What do I need to commit and compile changes made in these .java files to the ant-tibco.jar file?

Any help is greatly appreciatted! Thank you!

Comment: Extract all java files to a folder then import it into eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The `ant-tibco` project is an Eclipse compatible project so this is probably the easiest way to build it rather than trying to use `javac` from the command line. You can download Eclipse from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

To build it, first extract `ant-tibco.zip`. Open Eclipse and create a new workspace *outside* the location of ant-tibco (it will ask to create a new workspace when you open it). Then import the project into Eclipse by right clicking in the 'Package Explorer'. In the Import window choose 'General\Existing Projects into Workspace' and select the location of the extracted `ant-tibco` directory. <s>it will build automatically into the `ant-tibco.jar` file in the `ant-tibco\lib` directory.</s>

EDIT: You will need to download the ant libraries from [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.6.2-bin.zip) and reference them into the project. Eclipse will build the `.class` files into `classes\org\apache\tools\ant\taskdefs\optional\tibco`. Then see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse) for how to export a `.jar` file for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very very much for your answers.

I managed to open in eclipse and make the changes, followed the link to export the .jar, and the classes within the jar do have the changes....
But when I run the jar, it does not assume those changes, and I cannot figure why :(