# How do I export a project in Eclipse to jar with both external libraries and resources?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

My project in eclipse has both resources in `res` folder and external libraries. I tried two options to export the project as an executable jar.

1) I tried to export it using the `Export -> Runnable Jar` option. However, when I run the `jar`, I get the resource file not found exception/error.

When I tried to export it I get the following warning:

```
Fat Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry for 'home/../res'
```

I selected the option `Package required libraries into generared JAR`.

So, my problem here is that I can't include my `resource` folder with this option. Specific line problem is that:
`myClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/myFile.json")`.

2) Secondly I tried exporting with `Export -> JAR file`. Now, I can't include the external libraries that I am using. I can include the `resource` folder by selecting `resources to export`. However, there's no option to include external libraries. I tried `Export all output folders for checked projects`. When I run the generated JAR file, I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error.

So, my questions is how can I include both the external libraries and the resource folder I am using to export my project as jar in Eclipse.

Comment: You'll need to put myFile.json in your JAR file. Put it in one of your packages before you build.

Comment: If I want to keep that in the `resource` folder itself, is there any way out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse

Comment: @hurricane My second option is exactly that, and I am not getting external libraries and it throws error.

Comment: Download different version of Eclipse and try with it?

Comment: Using the "Export As Runnable" and a working "Launch configuration" I get a jar containing the external jars (first part of the reported question here), but the second part of including the resources dir from CLASSPATH is not working. I get warning:
  Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
  Fat   Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry for 'C:myProj/resource-1'
  Fat Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry for 'C:myProj/resource-2'
These are resources in my class-path in my Launch config and work perfectly when run from Eclipse