# How to host and run the GCM XMPP CCS Server 24x7 on Internet?

Tags: eclipse, google-cloud-messaging, smack

I have got a GCM Client app and a GCM CCS XMPP server running in my pc.

The GCM XMPP Server is based on the Sample GCM XMPP Server provided by google.

I can run the server from eclipse by running the server.java file but I want to know **how can I run the server file 24x7**.

Do I need to host the server file somewhere and can I run the server on a hosting website?

I've searched stack overflow about this but most of the questions doesn't have any answer or they are off-topic.

**I need to host and run the GCM XMPP Server file 24x7 somewhere and I don't know how to do it.**

Also, is there any other way I can **run the server file outside eclipse**?

Answer (score 1):

> Also, is there any other way I can run the server file outside eclipse?

1. Export your program as a JAR (Java archive) file. See [Java: export to an .jar file in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse)
2. `java -jar myprogram.jar`

> I can run the server from eclipse by running the server.java file but I want to know how can I run the server file 24x7.

1. Rent a virtual machine from some hosting. For example, from Amazon EC2
   (but there are plenty of others, of course).
2. Upload your JAR file there via SSH and run it (`java -jar myprogram.jar` again). Profit!

But of course it's not as easy as it sounds when you do all of that for the first time, you'll probably have a lot of issues. But hey, such an experience generally worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need a virtual machine only you need a website with more general backend like sqlite.

I'm also stuck at this point.Please tell me about your solution and also please take a look at the questions i have asked they will sort us both out of our problems.